Assembly : error concerning which type of register is used
I am assigned to make an assembly code that does the following task :
Write an assembler program that is given a parameter n∈{0,1,...,58} and iteratively determines the nth TUDO number in a loop. The correct result (e.g. f(58) = 2983297010) should be output and the program should then be terminated correctly. The result of the program should be in register a0 at the end. The specification is given below. Comment on the individual steps!
The task is for me to complete the unfinished code so that it runs correctly.
This is the unfinished code :
.data 
  n: .word 58 
.text 
.globl solution 
solution: 
lw x11, n # Lade Wert für n in Register x11 (Zählregister) 
li x5,-1 # initialisiere das Ergebnisregister 
li x6, 3 # Lade Abbruchbedingung für die Sonderfälle in x6 
   # Hier sollte ihr Code stehen 


# Behandlung der Zahlen 0- 2 
sonderfaelle: 
blt x11, x0, ende # Abbruch wenn n erreicht wurde 
addi x11,x11,-1 # Zählregister anpassen 
addi x6,x6,-1 # Zählregister für Sonderfälle (n < 3) anpassen 
addi x5,x5,1 # Ergebnisregister erhöhen (für 0- 2) 
### Ausgabe f(n) für 0- 2(nur für Aufgabenteil b relevant) 
add x10, x5, x0 # Wert für die Ausgabe vorbereiten (Pseudo-op: mv) 
li x17, 36 # Syscall zur Ausgabe eines vorzeichenlosen Integers 
ecall # Syscall ausführen 
addi x10, x0, 0xA # Lade das Zeichen für den Zeilenumbruch 
li x17, 11 # Syscall zur Ausgabe eines Zeichens laden 
ecall # Syscall ausführen 
### Ende der Ausgabe bne x6,x0, sonderfaelle # Sprung zum Anfang der Schleife solange n < 3 

schleife: 
  # Hier sollte ihr Code stehen 

ende: 
  # Hier sollte ihr Code stehen 
ret

This is my attempt : which ends with error 134:
.data 
  n: .word 58 
.text 
.globl solution 
solution: 
lw x11, n           # Load value for n into register x11 (counter)
li x5,-1           # Initialize result register
li x6, 3           # Load termination condition for special cases into x6

# Initialize registers for f(n-1) and f(n-3)
li x7, 2           # f(2)
li x8, 1           # f(1)
li x9, 0           # f(0)

# Handle numbers 0-2
sonderfaelle:
blt x11, x0, ende  # Exit if n is reached
addi x11,x11,-1    # Adjust counter
addi x6,x6,-1      # Adjust counter for special cases (n < 3)
addi x5,x5,1       # Increment result register (for 0-2)
### Output f(n) for 0-2 (only relevant for part b)
add x10, x5, x0    # Prepare value for output (Pseudo-op: mv)
li x17, 36         # Syscall for unsigned integer output
ecall              # Execute syscall
addi x10, x0, 0xA  # Load newline character
li x17, 11         # Syscall for character output
ecall              # Execute syscall
### End of output
bne x6,x0, sonderfaelle # Jump to start of loop while n < 3

schleife:
beq x11, x0, ende  # Exit loop if counter reaches 0
# Calculate f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-3)
add x28, x7, x9    # x28 = f(n-1) + f(n-3)
# Shift values
mv x9, x8          # f(0) = f(1)
mv x8, x7          # f(1) = f(2)
mv x7, x28         # f(2) = new value
mv x5, x28         # Store result in x5
addi x11, x11, -1  # Decrement counter
j schleife         # Continue loop

ende:
mv x10, x5         # Move final result to x10 for return
ret                # Return from function

This is the error message i keep getting :
src/sim/faults.cc:102: panic: panic condition !handled && !tc->getSystemPtr()->trapToGdb(GDBSignal::SEGV, tc->contextId()) occurred: Page table fault when accessing virtual address 0x52c97fb8
Memory Usage: 626276 KBytes
Program aborted at tick 410304000
--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem515print_backtraceEv+0x19)[0x560bdff41299]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem512abortHandlerEi+0x3d)[0x560bdff66e9d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3c050)[0x7efcfbe62050]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8aebc)[0x7efcfbeb0ebc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x12)[0x7efcfbe61fb2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0xd3)[0x7efcfbe4c472]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(+0xcd058f)[0x560bdf95a58f]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem521GenericPageTableFault6invokeEPNS_13ThreadContextERKNS_14RefCountingPtrINS_10StaticInstEEE+0xc5)[0x560bdffd63c5]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem513BaseSimpleCPU9advancePCERKSt10shared_ptrINS_9FaultBaseEE+0xc8)[0x560bdfa586c8]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem515TimingSimpleCPU11advanceInstERKSt10shared_ptrINS_9FaultBaseEE+0xa9)[0x560bdfa4af59]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem515TimingSimpleCPU17finishTranslationEPNS_21WholeTranslationStateE+0xf6)[0x560bdfa4e766]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem515DataTranslationIPNS_15TimingSimpleCPUEE6finishERKSt10shared_ptrINS_9FaultBaseEERKS4_INS_7RequestEEPNS_13ThreadContextENS_7BaseMMU4ModeE+0xf1)[0x560bdfa54171]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem58RiscvISA3TLB15translateTimingERKSt10shared_ptrINS_7RequestEEPNS_13ThreadContextEPNS_7BaseMMU11TranslationENS9_4ModeE+0x8a)[0x560be0455c6a]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem515TimingSimpleCPU8writeMemEPhjmNS_5FlagsImEEPmRKSt6vectorIbSaIbEE+0x6d3)[0x560bdfa50203]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem517SimpleExecContext8writeMemEPhjmNS_5FlagsImEEPmRKSt6vectorIbSaIbEE+0x42)[0x560bdfa59b52]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem514writeMemTimingILNS_9ByteOrderE1ENS_11ExecContextEmEESt10shared_ptrINS_9FaultBaseEEPT0_PNS_5trace10InstRecordET1_mNS_5FlagsImEEPm+0x64)[0x560be08e3034]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZNK4gem512RiscvISAInst2Sd11initiateAccEPNS_11ExecContextEPNS_5trace10InstRecordE+0xf6)[0x560be07c0ea6]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem515TimingSimpleCPU14completeIfetchEPNS_6PacketE+0x172)[0x560bdfa4bd62]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem510EventQueue10serviceOneEv+0x12d)[0x560bdff575fd]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem59doSimLoopEPNS_10EventQueueE+0x58)[0x560bdff80b98]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem58simulateEm+0x27e)[0x560bdff812ae]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(+0x14a7fdc)[0x560be0131fdc]
/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt(+0xce280e)[0x560bdf96c80e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(+0x1c9be3)[0x7efcfc50abe3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(_PyObject_Call+0x54)[0x7efcfc4c0014]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x55d3)[0x7efcfc44b7d3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(+0x3cce8c)[0x7efcfc70de8c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0xc1)[0x7efcfc5a98b1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(+0x268fd0)[0x7efcfc5a9fd0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(+0x1ca0e2)[0x7efcfc50b0e2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(PyObject_Vectorcall+0x33)[0x7efcfc4be633]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4a63)[0x7efcfc44ac63]
--- END LIBC BACKTRACE ---

Aborted (core dumped)
make: *** [Makefile:22: case_1.out] Error 134```





Please provide the error message you get.  Also, what architecture are you programming for?

The error message is edited in
As for this case i am not using rars to run the code instead its a built in simulator in our uni website , all i can provide is that its strict with which types of register it uses

Looks like a bug in your simulator. BTW, you seem to have an off by one error somewhere since the code produces 2035586497 which is supposedly f(57). It produces what you have specified for n=59. Does the code run for smaller numbers? Check n=1 which should not enter the loop you have coded and n=4 which should do just one iteration.

What is your question and is it related to the title (type of register)?

the question is why am i getting that error and how can i fix it

Ok, what is it about type of register that you think is relevant?
